# Prior predictive distribution

Tags: distribution, bayesian, predictive

How to generate samples form prior predictive distribution for simple regression models? 
it is straightforward to generate samples for a binomial distribution with a beta prior, but in regression models, can we simulate both the covariate and parameters  based on prior information?